# Listview: Add arrows as dividers

Tags: android, android-listview, styling

I would like to add arrows as dividers between my listview items. I've gotten pretty far, but my arrow is stretched and there is no option to set the divider width. Here is what I have so far...
In my styles.xml:

```
   <style name="dividedListStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
        <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@drawable/baseline_expand_more_black_24</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">50dp</item>
    </style>
```

Then in my layout file:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/checklist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    style="@style/dividedListStyle">
</ListView>
```

This is what the divider looks like: 
[image]

This is what I need: 
[image]

Comment: please paste `row.xml` of listview

Comment: the divider is stretched to full width. So to keep the arrow aspect ratio, you need either make it a 9-patch, or a part of a layer drawable for example. As alternative, you can make the arrow a part of your list item

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I made it a layer drawable and it worked! Don't know why I didn't think of that. Thank you so much for your help! If you want, please post this as an answer and I'll mark it as correct?

Comment: ok, let me make an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListView` divider is stretched to full width of the `ListView` and your selected height (`<item name="android:dividerHeight">50dp</item>`). That's why your image is stretched.

To avoid it and keep the size/ratio unchanged, there are such ways:

1. Use 9-patch drawable. You may use a default Android 9-patch editor to convert your arrow to 9-patch (you still need some basic knowledge about how 9-patch works)
2. Make your arrow drawable a part of the drawable or a layer-list drawable:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/baseline_expand_more_black_24">
</bitmap>
```